# Problema con zoom.js y modal de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Estoy usando la librería de zoom.js de [Fat](https://github.com/fat/zoom.js/) y los modales de Boostrap 4, cuando le agrego la clase de `modal-dialog-scrollable`, con ello aparece la barra de scroll, pero cuando la imagen hace zoom, se queda detrás del modal, no sobresale de él como cuando no tiene la clase.

Cuando **Sí** tiene la clase `modal-dialog-scrollable`:
[image: Cuando Sí tiene la clase]

Cuando **NO** tiene la clase `modal-dialog-scrollable`:
[image: Cuando no tiene la clase]

Ya probé modificando el CSS y agregando que el `z-index` sea 9999, pero sigue igual. ¿Alguna idea de como hacer que salga del modal?.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zoom-vanilla.js/dist/zoom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zoom-vanilla.js/dist/zoom-vanilla.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-scroll">
  Modal con scroll
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-scroll" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="https://scd.france24.com/es/files/espanol/imagecache/rfi_16x9_1024_578/article/image/gato.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid" alt="image" data-action="zoom">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-sin-scroll">
  Modal sin scroll
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-sin-scroll" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="https://scd.france24.com/es/files/espanol/imagecache/rfi_16x9_1024_578/article/image/gato.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid" alt="image" data-action="zoom">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agrega tu código a la pregunta para que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, es que no tiene ciencia el código la verdad, pero ya te lo agrego...

Comment: te sugiero aplicar un z-index al modal mas no a la imagen algo asi ".modal-fade{z-index:....}"

Comment: @DiegoAvila La verdad no creo que sea lo mas apropiado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo el código fuente de [`zoom-valilla.js`](https://github.com/spinningarrow/zoom-vanilla.js/blob/master/js/zoom-vanilla.js#L133), actualmente, sin sobrecargar métodos del mismo con `JS` y **desde mi punto de vista**, la única forma que veo es aumentar el `z-index` de las clases `.zoom-img, .zoom-img-wrap`.

Por defecto la clase `.modal` de Bootstrap 4  tiene `z-index: 1050`.
Esto quiere decir que cualquier elemento con un `z-index` superior a `1050` debe aparece por encima del mismo.

### Solución

```
<style>
.zoom-img, .zoom-img-wrap {
  z-index: 2000;
}
</style>
```

#### Demo

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zoom-vanilla.js/dist/zoom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zoom-vanilla.js/dist/zoom-vanilla.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- PISAMOS ESTILOS -->
<style>
.zoom-img, .zoom-img-wrap {
  z-index: 2000;
}
</style>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-scroll">
  Modal con scroll
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-scroll" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="https://scd.france24.com/es/files/espanol/imagecache/rfi_16x9_1024_578/article/image/gato.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid" alt="image" data-action="zoom">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-sin-scroll">
  Modal sin scroll
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-sin-scroll" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="https://scd.france24.com/es/files/espanol/imagecache/rfi_16x9_1024_578/article/image/gato.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid" alt="image" data-action="zoom">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vaya, lo había intentado así y no me había funcionado, pero lo cambié por zoom-vanilla.js y sí lo tomó, muchas gracias amigo, me has salvado.